# assigning dates using regex, converting them with strptime and then applying to dataframe using lambda. Code works but pytest is failing?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, lambda, pytest

I was wondering if i could get some help on this code? The function is assigning dates using regex, converting them with strptime and then applying to dataframe using lambda. Code works but pytest is failing and i have no idea why?

Here is the code for you to look at:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import re
import pandas as pd


def conv_date(dte: str) -> date:
    acceptable_mappings = {
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",

    }

    for regex in acceptable_mappings.keys():
        if re.fullmatch(regex, dte):
            return datetime.strptime(dte, acceptable_mappings[regex]).date()
    raise Exception(f"Expected date in one of supported formats, got {dte}")


def full_list_parse(unclean_list: list) -> list:
    return [conv_date(dte) for dte in unclean_list]


mock_dict = [
    {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": "2023-07-26 12:46:21"},

]

df = pd.DataFrame(mock_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(df)
    df['date_clean'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: conv_date(x))
    print(df)
```

When i run the above code i get back which is desired. The date to be converted to 2023-07-26:

```
  name             role                 date
0   xx  loves only-fans  2023-07-26 12:46:21
  name             role                 date  date_clean
0   xx  loves only-fans  2023-07-26 12:46:21  2023-07-26
```

And here is my test:

```
from x import *
import pytest


class TestConvDate:
    classical_programming_with_datetime = "2023-07-26 12:46:21"

    def test_classical_programming_with_datetime(self):
        assert datetime(2023, 7, 26) == conv_date(self.classical_programming_with_datetime)

    def test_error_is_raised(self):
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            conv_date("some issue")
```

But when i run this test, i get this error!

```
Expected :datetime.date(2023, 7, 26)
Actual   :datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 26, 0, 0)
```

Do I need to assert differently, i thought my function handles the time portion of the datetime? Where are these zeros coming from? I tried changing the assert to:

`assert datetime(2023, 7, 26, 0, 0) == conv_date(self.classical_programming_with_datetime)`

but im still getting the same error!
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error you converted the date in the Dataframe to datetime.date type and you asserting on datetime.datetime which is a different one, the extra zeros are hours and minutes

Why not just assert on `datetime.date` ?

```
def test_classical_programming_with_datetime(self):
        assert date(2023, 7, 26) == conv_date(self.classical_programming_with_datetime)
```